# Xcode copies images everytime I compile my project.

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I build my current iPhone project, it copies every single picture I've added to the project into a new resources folder.

I didn't realize this until today but now I have a resource folder thats 1GB full of the same photos that have been copied over and over again.

When I build it says: `Copying xAmount of xAmount resources to product`

Is there anyway for me to turn this off so it only copies new images that have been added?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's because when you drag images to project you didn't check to copy resources to destination folder? And each time it's copying because it has only references to those images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you import resource files on your project, be sure to have: "copy items into destination group's folder if needed" option checked.

Comment: Yea I just realized this... should have started doing it 150 pictures ago which are scattered throughout my project.. oh well learn from your failures right!